# Running Docker as a syslog-ng destination fails

Tags: python, docker, syslog-ng

I have a Vagrant-created VM running stock Ubuntu Trusty 64, with one host CPU allocated to it.
Within that VM, I have a Docker image running stock Python 3.4.3:

```
FROM python:3.4.3-slim

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/python"]
```

When I execute an arbitrary Python script:

```python
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Like this:

```bash
sudo docker run -i -v /etc/alloy_listener/scripts:/scripts:ro alloy_listener /scripts/test.py
```

Everything is fine, the container run and just sits there doing very little. If I add print statements to the Python script, it gets sent to stdout as expected.

I also have syslog-ng installed in that VM, and my intention is to use my containerized Python to act as syslog-ng destination:

```
source s_foo {
  unix-stream("/dev/log");
};

destination d_foo {
  program("'docker run -i -v /etc/alloy_listener/scripts:/scripts:ro alloy_listener /scripts/test.py'");
};

log {
  source(s_foo);
  destination(d_foo);
};
```

But when I reload the config, syslog-ng consumes about 20% of the VM's CPU, and 100% of the host's CPU, and the container never gets created (running `sudo docker ps -a` yields no containers). Running `sudo syslog-ng-ctl stats` tells me that it is trying to execute the program:

```
dst.program;d_foo#0;'docker run -i -v /etc/alloy_listener/scripts:/scripts:ro alloy_listener /scripts/test.py';a;dropped;0
dst.program;d_foo#0;'docker run -i -v /etc/alloy_listener/scripts:/scripts:ro alloy_listener /scripts/test.py';a;processed;2
dst.program;d_foo#0;'docker run -i -v /etc/alloy_listener/scripts:/scripts:ro alloy_listener /scripts/test.py';a;stored;0
```

My feeling is that because syslog-ng is using 20% of its CPU, but 100% of the host's, it's I/O bound and the VM is working extra-hard to keep up. To that end I tried consuming and flushing stdin and stdout in the Python script, but as far as I can tell because it's not even creating the container, it isn't getting as far as the script.

So my next thought was there must be some combination of docker's `-a`, `-d`, `-i`, and `-t` flags that I've not tried, but I'm sure I have tried every permissible combination to no avail.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start syslog-ng in foreground (syslog-ng-binary -Fedv) you see that  syslog-ng starts and stops the program destination in a loop, this cause the 100% CPU spining.
But after investigating the problem locally, you should use the program destination as (without '):
program("sudo docker run -i -v /scripts:/scripts python-test /scripts/test.py");

Br,
Micek

Comment: That's fixed it - I can't believe it was just those extra single quotes. I'm not even sure where they came from - I must have added them at some point for some reason and never taken them out. Thanks Micek.